# Make one method in view controller globally and call it to many view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, methods, global

I want to make one single method and call it, to many view controllers. Help me? and i also want to alloc UIView or button or label on that Fixed View.

**HERE IS MY CODE**

**.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIOnlyView : UIView

+ (UIOnlyView *) sharedGlobalClass;

-(void)yourMethod;

@end
```

**.m**

```
+(UIOnlyView *)sharedGlobalClass {

static dispatch_once_t pred;
static id shared = nil;

dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
    shared = [[super alloc] init];

});

return shared;
}

-(void)yourMethod{

NSLog(@"Method called");

UIView *customView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];

    customView.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];

    [self addSubview:customView];

}
```

**But my Custom view is not show on my view controller class where i called this method.**

Comment: Use Singleton class or declare the method in appdelegate.

Comment: I know sir but i want full code. If you have so please share it with me.

Comment: Your project is swift based or objective c ?

Comment: My code is based on Objective-C

Comment: Dear you can create your custom view in View Controller Class, It easy to create singleton and optimized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `singleton` like this

create a class for example `GlobalClass` with type `NSObject`

In .h class create this method

```
+ (GlobalClass *) sharedGlobalClass;
- (void) yourMethod : (UIView *) view;
```

Now in .m class

```
+ (GlobalClass *) sharedGlobalClass {

    static dispatch_once_t pred;
    static id shared = nil;

    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
        shared = [[super alloc] init];

    });


    return shared;
}

- (void) yourMethod : (UIView *) view {
    UIView *customView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];

    customView.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];

    [view addSubview:customView];
}
```

Now you can call this method like this

```
[[GlobalClass sharedGlobalClass] yourMethod:self.view];
```

from any of your ViewController, you just have to import

```
#import "GlobalClass.h"
```

Comment: Sir i also want to add view or button or label or anything on  "yourMethod" . I add it but nothing happen. Please suggest me.

Comment: If you want to add something then you need to pass the UIView also on which you want to add Button or UIViews

Comment: I did it but UIView is not visible.

Comment: BTW that is another question, which is not mentioned in your question

Comment: Update your question with proper code which you have implemented and what you are expecting

Comment: I mentioned that i want to call a method to many controllers.

Comment: And you can call this method in Many Controllers there is no issue in it, you have not mentioned what you want in this method

Comment: But when i add something in this method it can not show anything.. The method is called but nothing visible on my controller.

Comment: Again I am saying, either update your question or post a new question as what is your expected result, what you want to achieve and what you have tried with your actual code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129530/discussion-between-dishant-rajput-and-rajat).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the singleton class for this purpose:

create a NSObject class:

```
import <foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyManager : NSObject {
    NSString *someProperty;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *someProperty;

+ (id)sharedManager;

@end
```

In your .m file:

## import "MyManager.h"

```
@implementation MyManager

@synthesize someProperty;

+ (id)sharedManager {
    static MyManager *sharedMyManager = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedMyManager = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedMyManager;
}
```

you can use the someProperty globally in all class.
it defines a static variable initialised once and only once in sharedManager.

for more info: http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/
https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/design-patterns-singletons--cms-23886

Answer (score 0):

In Objective C:

```
@interface OUCSCalendarManager ()
- (void)globalMethod;
@end

@implementation OUCSCSharedManager

/// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
/// Singleton Method
///--------------------------------------------------------------------------

+(instancetype)SharedManager{

    @synchronized(self) {

    static OUCSCalendarManager *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t pred;
        @synchronized (self) {
            dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
                sharedInstance = [[OUCSCalendarManager alloc]init];
            });
            return sharedInstance;
        }
    }
}

- (void)globalMethod {
 }
}
```

To Call That method from anywhere in project you need to create the singleton object and call method like this

```
[[OUCSCalendarManager calendarSharedManager]globalMethod];
```

Let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: When i alloc UIVIEW in your "global method" .My view is not visible. Method is called but nothing happen.

Answer (score 0):

**ClassA.h**

```
#import "ClassA.h"

@interface ClassA : NSObject

+(id)sharedInstance;
-(void)customMethod;


@end
```

Now Implementation of **ClassA.m**

```
#import "ClassA.h"

@implementation ClassA


+(id)sharedInstance
{
    static ClassA *instance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        instance = [[ClassA alloc] init];
    });
    return instance;
}

-(void)customMethod
{
  //Method body
}
```

Now import the header file in other viewcontrollers  and use it like

```
[[ClassA sharedInstance] customMethod{}];
```